# Scrolling UITableView like FaceBook

Tags: iphone, ios

If you look into Facebook "App" for iOS, scrolling of the `UITableView` is very fast. It seems like the app is rendering data into cell in different thread (not in main thread).

I'm also developing a similar application. But my app scrolling speed is not good. I'm using lazy loading of images. Even then the scrolling speed is poor.

Is it possible to populate custom `UITableViewCell` in different thread (not in main thread)????

Thanks for reply

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374979/update-uitableview-using-threads - Try this

Comment: Just a quick answer, not a full solution, you should access the data on a background thread, but **always** update the UI on the main thread

Answer (score 1):

Suppose You have Following Tasks Per UITableViewCell

1. **GetData From Service**
2. **Fetch Image from service**
3. **Resize image To match container size** (You should do this if image you get is large)
4. **Display your Data**.

You Should perform 1 , 2 , 3 in Background

**But You have to and you should do the 4 in Main Thread.**

***Don't create a separate thread for each and every tableview cell*** and then again 3 for tasks 1 , 2 , 3. Its really wasting of resources.

So How you can do all these background without creating a thread for each and every thing.

Use **GRAND CENTRAL DISPATCH** (GCD)

Read on GCD.

If you want a quick workaround Here it is

Well. Task Number 4 has two things to do.

*4(a) Update Some text on table cell for Date we get.
4(b) Display Fetched and Resized Image.*

I'm Taking
**1**    and    **4(a)**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

       1. DO 1 Here
       2. Call a Call Back When your Task is Done
        example
        CallBack(Response);

});


CallBack(Response *)response{

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        Do your 4(a) Here
   });
}
```